# Regarding Joins in LinQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list collection and a Datatable on which I am trying do a join via linq but am getting the below error.

> The type of one of the expressions in the join clause is incorrect. 
>   Type inference failed in the call to `join`

My LinQ Query is :

```
var linqresultset = from e in emp_data 
join d in dt on e.DeptId equals d.ID orderby e.Id 
select new { Id = e.Id, Name = e.Name +" - "+ d.Department };
```

What is wrong in the systax?

Comment: Check the data types of `e.DepId` and `d.ID`

Answer (score 2):

`DataTable` does not implement `IEnumerable`, so you cannot use it in LINQ query like this directly, you need to convert it to type IEnumerable using [AsEnumerable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatableextensions.asenumerable%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) like this:-

```
var linqresultset = from e in emp_data 
join d in dt.AsEnumerable() on e.DeptId equals d.Field<int>("ID") 
orderby e.Id 
select new { Id = e.Id, Name = e.Name +" - "+ d.Field<string>("Department ")};
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `.Cast<T>()`, rather than `.AsEnumerable()`? The latter expects the source to be `IEnumerable<T>` to start with.

Comment: @Enigmativity no, it's a different AsEnumerable method.  Here are the correct MSDN docs: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatableextensions.asenumerable%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: @Jon - Thanks Jon, I was updating the same :)